# Template function type deduction, and return type

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Why `a` is `true`, and `b` is `false`? Or in other words why `T` in `foo1` is `int const` but return type of `foo2` is just `int`?

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool foo1(T &) {
    return std::is_const<T>::value;
}

template<typename T>
T foo2(T &);

int main() {
    int const x = 0;
    constexpr bool a = foo1(x);
    constexpr bool b = std::is_const<decltype(foo2(x))>::value;
}
```

Comment: I'm not checking foo1 return type. Look closely.

Comment: Oh, misread. This is a dupe then.

Comment: @Incomputable That's a different rule for parameter types.

Comment: @T.C., it mentions removing constness in top-level

Comment: Oh yes, I definitely misread. It'd be nice if you remove the `constexpr` red herring, however.

Comment: @Incomputable of *function parameters*. A completely different rule is involved here.

Comment: @T.C., I see now. I thought foo2 is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

const-qualifiers are ignored if function returned type is non-class, non-array type. If you use some class instead of plain `int` it will produce 1 1:

```
  struct Bar{};

  int main()
  {
     Bar const x{};
     constexpr bool a = foo1(x);
     constexpr bool b = std::is_const<decltype(foo2(x))>::value;
  }
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qcUdkQP8BBoPjB9l)

Answer (score 6):

The specialization called, `const int foo2<const int>(const int&);`, has a return type of `const int`, so `foo2(x)` would have been a prvalue of type `const int`. However, There are no `const` (or `volatile`) prvalues of non-array, non-class type (in your case, `int`). The constness is adjusted away ["prior to any further analysis"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type#2), and it becomes simply a prvalue of type `int`, which `decltype` reports.